# PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “warning: A non-numeric value encountered”

Tags: php

I am running a PHP script, and keep getting errors like:
Notice: Undefined variable: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\alenayahpharmacy\cart.php on line 128

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\alenayahpharmacy\cart.php on line 129

Line 128 and 129 looks like this:

```
$pricetotal=$price*$each_item['quantity'];              
$carttotal=$pricetotal+$carttotal;
```

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Undefined variable: price" I mean it is clear enough what is the issue isn't it ?

Comment: These error's are pretty clear right? `$price` does not have a value set to it and `$pricetotal` or `$carttotal` have a non-numeric value. What is your problem?

Comment: Yes $price does not contain any value, that's why such error comes.

Comment: Please show more code, especially where your variables are initialized.

Comment: $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from product_details where product_code='$item_id' limit 1");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
     $productname=$row['product_name'];
     
     $productcode=$row['product_code'];
          
     $price=$row['product_price'];
     
     $img=$row['product_img'];
     }

Answer (score 1):

It simply means $price does not exist and therefore its null which leads to the second error.

Comment: Sorry it should be a comment, im new to the mobile app :)

Comment: Looks like an ok answer to me.